# Redraw Google Maps Circle and Marker on function call

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-maps-markers

I'm writing a web application that shows one Circle around one Marker on a Google Map. `placeMarker(location, radius)` sets a a Marker at `location` and binds to it a Circle with a radius. I want the script to redraw the Circle and Marker every time placeMarker is called. When I try it in a console, it redraws the Marker with the new location but the original Circle radius is kept. `undefined` is also printed. What do I need to change to get this working?

```
var map;
var marker;

function placeMarker(location, radius) {
    if (typeof radius === 'undefined') { radius = initialRadius; }

    if (marker) {
        marker.setPosition(location);
    } else {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            map: map,
            draggable: true
        });
    }

    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        map: map,
        radius: radius,
        fillColor: '#AA0000',
    });

    circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
}


function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: 0, lng: 0},
        zoom: 1
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
        placeMarker(event.latLng);
    });

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function () {
        var center = map.getCenter();
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
        map.setCenter(center);
    });
}
```

Comment: With the posted code, I get a javascript error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: initialRadius is not defined`.  If I fix that, [it works as I expect](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/e9v5kL9s/) (and the way I think you want it to, except the circle gets darker everytime the map is clicked).  I don't see any mechanism to change the radius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to do something similar to your marker. That is, instead of creating a new `circle` object and binding it to the map. You need to reposition the existing circle using the `circle.setCenter(latlng)` api.

**See:**
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Circle

Unfortunately you don't have a JSFiddle setup here or otherwise I could have try fixing it there for you. However your code **should** look like this.

```
var map;
var marker;
var myCircle;

function placeMarker(location, radius) {
    if (typeof radius === 'undefined') { radius = initialRadius; }

    if (marker) {
        marker.setPosition(location);
    } else {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            map: map,
            draggable: true
        });
    }

    if (myCircle) {
        // Don't create new circle, update circle position instead. 
        myCircle.setCenter(location); // where location=latLng
    }
    else {
        // First time loading, create the circle
        myCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
            map: map,
            radius: radius,
            fillColor: '#AA0000',
        });

        myCircle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
    }
}


function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: 0, lng: 0},
        zoom: 1
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
        placeMarker(event.latLng);
    });

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function () {
        var center = map.getCenter();
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
        map.setCenter(center);
    });
}
```

Comment: Let me know if this works for you. Happy to discuss further.